# Network Related Error in SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server

I have a server in my head office. I am trying to connect that SQL Server database from my system. But I am getting network related error. I will explain my issue details.

I have main SQL Server in my head office. I will connect that database from my system using a public IP address. That is in my head office after connecting modem (internet connection) they will generate an IP address. Using that IP address I will connect that main server database in my application.

Now while I'm trying to connect that database, I am getting network related or instant error. I tried many ways to resolve this issue by generating a new IP address like that. But issue is not solved. Can anyone provide a suggestion how to solve this problem?

The error is mention in the below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with your FIREWALL. MSDN documentation can help you in this situation and here are some helpful links that can be handy.

[Link-1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326282.aspx) that helps you identify the cause of the issue.

[Link-2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2008/11/07/sql-server-error-10060-sql-server-error-10061/) will help you resolve the issue. The scenario that you are facing is clearly explained in the error scenario - 2 of this blog. Please take a look at this.

Hope that these links help you understand your problem and resolve them as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you think all setup is ok then Please try this

Restart **SQL Server Service** from **local services** in your head office server.

I always stuck in this problem.